# How to access BIOS information from a Windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-8, wmi

I know we can get the BIOS information using system.management assembly but the assembly is not accessible for windows 8 app. I specifically need to know the serial number of the laptop on which the app is running. Is there any way that I can access that ?

Comment: What are you tryng to do? Licensing? There are other concepts...

Comment: I have an app which has to be usable only for HP devices. So i need to get the device serial number and validate it with a db containing HP device serial numbers. Any idea how i can get the serial number at the start of the app ?

Comment: Via command prompt: WMIC BASEBOARD GET Manufacturer /VALUE

Comment: Ya i realized we cant access command prompt also from a windows 8 app. We cant access any executable from windows 8 app :( Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way if you are developing a Windows Modern UI App.
Modern UI Apps get run in a sandbox environment which have very limited access to anything. Check MSDN documentations on that.
If you are developing a desktop Windows app on the other hand, then try the following code:

**(You need to import `System.Management.dll` into your project.)**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;

namespace GetHardwareIds
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\HardwareInfo.txt"))
            {
                using
                (
                    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    // Where __Superclass Is Null: selects only top-level classes.
                    // remove it if you need a list of all classes
                    // new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From meta_class Where __Superclass Is Null")
                    // this query only select the processor info. for more options uncomment top line
                        new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From meta_class Where __Class = 'Win32_Processor'")
                )
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in searcher.Get())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(managementObject.Path.ClassName);
                        writer.WriteLine(managementObject.Path.ClassName);
                        GetManagementClassProperties(managementObject.Path.ClassName, writer);
                        managementObject.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void GetManagementClassProperties(string path, StreamWriter writer)
        {
            using (ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass(path))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject instance in managementClass.GetInstances())
                {
                    foreach (PropertyData property in instance.Properties)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("  {0} = {1}", property.Name, property.Value);
                        writer.WriteLine("  {0} = {1}", property.Name, property.Value);
                    }

                    instance.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need it in windows 8 app only. I have an app which has to be usable only for HP devices. So i need to get the device serial number and validate it with a db containing HP device serial numbers. Any idea how i can get the serial number at the start of the app ?

Comment: Check this code. I am not a 100% clear on what you are trying to achieve but this code should return the device ID specified by Win8. Not sure that this is what you need though:

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. I am not a 100% clear on what you are trying to achieve but this code should return the device ID specified by Win8 (this code includes a concatenation of all ids.)

```
// get hardware token
HardwareToken token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
// get hardware ID bytes
byte[] idBytes = hwToken.Id.ToArray();
// populate device ID as a string value
string deviceID = string.Join(",", idBytes);
```

Here is the link to MSDN articles about it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken.aspx
There is an entry for BIOS in the return structure based on these articles.
Hopefully, this does what you need. Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Unfortunately this id is not unique. It keeps changing based on any hardware changes or even if the app is reinstalled.

Comment: based on the MSDN article, the BIOS section should have what you need and it does not change. Did you read thru the article?

Comment: Yes i did. I didnt find any way to access the BIOS section. Could you please share some sample code if you know how to access the BIOS section

Comment: See if this link helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the information you want to obtain is not available to WinRT applications.